# How to theme maintenance page for omega subtheme?

Tags: theming, maintenance-mode

Drupal's ["Theming the Drupal maintenance page"](https://drupal.org/node/195435) gives a good overview for theming the maintenance page for 'normal' themes:

1. Copy `modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php` to your theme's templates directory
2. In the `settings.php` file, enable the `$conf['maintenance_theme']` variable
3. Copy you `page.tpl.php` contents into `maintenance-page.tpl.php` and edit as necessary

But my site uses an Omega subtheme, so I don't have a `page.tpl.php` (well, it's not quite the same as these instructions are anticipating).  I'm a little lost among all the omega templates & regions.

How do I theme my omega subtheme's maintence page to look like the rest of my site?

Comment: It'd be good to know what version of Omega you're using, things are very different between v3 and v4

Comment: Good point.  I'm working with Omega 3.x

Answer (score 1):

There's always a parent template, even if you don't see it in your base_theme.

The inheritance will go:

1. omega_subtheme template of NAME
2. then omega template of NAME
3. then drupal core template of name

So you'll need to copy the drupal core templates. They can be found in

```
DRUPALROOT/modules/system
```

You can find page.tpl, maintenance-page.tpl.php and all the base templates.